# How can I find the permutations of a string created by moving only the adjacent characters? - C++

Tags: c++, string, character, permutation

I have no idea to write a console application that calculate the permutations of a string created by moving only the adjacent characters.

```
Example: ABC
------>  ACB
------>  BAC
------------
Example: AUTO
------>  ATUO
------>  AUOT
------>  UATO
------>  UAOT
```

Besides, every character moved, can not move it a second time

```
Example: I can not do this: ATOU
```

Thanks so much for the patience

Comment: You could sort the letters and check the levenshtein distance. If the distance is exactly 2 and they both contain exactly the same letters, then this should mean that you've shifted exactly one letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider any i-th character in the string. There are two possibilities for this character:

- Don’t swap it, i.e. don’t do anything with this character and move to the next character.
- Swap it. As it can be swapped with its adjacent,

2nd case has two possibilities:

- Swap it with the next character. Because each character can be
  swapped atmost once, we’ll move to the position (i+2).
- Swap it with the previous character – we don’t need to consider this
  case separately as i-th character is the next character of (i-1)th
  which is same as the previous case

Here is a recursive solution:

```
void findPermutations(char str[], int index, int n)
{
    if (index >= n || (index + 1) >= n) {
        cout << str << endl;
        return;
    }

    // don't swap the current position
    findPermutations(str, index + 1, n);

    // Swap with the next character and
    // revert the changes. As explained
    // above, swapping with previous is
    // is not needed as it anyways happens
    // for next character.
    swap(str[index], str[index + 1]);
    findPermutations(str, index + 2, n);
    swap(str[index], str[index + 1]);
}
```

Output for `ABC`:

- ABC
- ACB
- BAC

Output for `AUTO`:

- AUTO
- AUOT
- ATUO
- UATO
- UAOT

You can extend it for the case when characters are not distinct.